# auto increment column increments even when there is NO new row insertion

Tags: mysql

I have created a table which is having a conditional row insertion function,so at times new rows are not inserted into the column. Here the problem is, even when row insertion is failed the auto_inc column increments and thus the values stored in that will be some what like this:

Sl No.

1

2

4

7

8

9

it looks really messy please help.thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste the error message while `INSERT` fails

Comment: there is no error!! There is 'where' condition if condition is true table is inserted with a row,else its not inserted...but auto increment is incrementing every time the condition is checked.sorry for using 'failed' in my question i will edit it.

Comment: I wrote up a gap answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363271). No reason to duplicate it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got an answer for this question thanks to @ juergen d
this should be the query:

```
    String queryString = "INSERT INTO hcl_candidates(SL_No,candidate,phone,pan,mailid) SELECT MAX(SL_No)+1, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM hcl_candidates";
```

Comment: This should work as well provided you have unique columns. It seems "on duplicate key update" avoids this behavior for me.

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO hcl_candidates(candidate,phone,pan,mailid) SELECT ?, ?, ?, ? FROM hcl_candidates on duplicate key update candidate=values(candidate), phone=values(phone), pan=values(pan), mailid=values(mailid)";
```

Answer (score 2):

A `sspencer7593` has mentioned 
  `"The behavior of AUTO_INCREMENT is fairly well defined. And it's primarily designed to generate unique values. It's not designed to prevent gaps."`

However as MySQL allows you to assign a custom value to `AUTO_INCREMENT` column a workaround to your scenario would be to assign value of Max(SI_No)+1 while inserting the row. In this case you will ensure that you would add next incremented value only when row is actually inserted.

Typical syntax would look like 
  `INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID,SOMECOLUMN) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID)+1 NEWID FROM TABLENAME) ,someValue);`

Note:- it would prevent gaps you are seeing during insertion and last row deletion cases . If you delete row in between you would still see the Gaps but I think this should be OK with you

Comment: i had a similar idea but i had a few doubt about it: 1)what should be data type 2)how to set intial value to zero

Comment: Normally we keep it `Integer`.   You can use nvl function which would return 0 incase there is no row present in table

Comment: sorry i am  pretty late but ,i used the same syntax and got an exception"You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: this is the query :'String queryString = "INSERT INTO tablename(SL_No,candidate,phone,pan,mailid) VALUES((MAX(SL_No)+1 SL_No from tablename), ?, ?, ?, ? ))";'

Comment: you missed `SELECT` in the VALUES clause for finding maximum SL_No

Comment: sorry that was an editing mistake. this is the query:"'String queryString = "INSERT INTO tablename(SL_No,candidate,phone,pan,mailid) VALUES (SELECT(MAX(SL_No)+1 SL_No from tablename), ?, ?, ?, ? ))";'"

Comment: So does this query worked for you... If yes please mention accordingly... So that other users won't be investing time for this question. You can accept appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction, i had to do some minor tweaks to your code. please check my answer to this question ...it works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add your php code and table structure? I think insert query is being executed even condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior with `INSERT ... SELECT`, or when an INSERT statement fails or is rolled back.  The  innodb_autoinc_lock_mode setting can also influence the behavior. We will also see this when a value is supplied for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, or when rows are deleted.

The behavior of AUTO_INCREMENT is fairly well defined. And it's primarily designed to generate unique values. It's not designed to prevent gaps.

Comment: so, can i create a procedure to replicate increment function depending on the where condition??