# Fill deleted numbers in consecutive series of numbers and LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: c#, mysql

First of all I'm an amateur and non-english native speaker, so I would appreciate it if you would have a little patience with me ;)

Trying to do two things here and I'm not sure if I should do two questions about it, but since it's all related in my case, I would like to say it all in one question.

I'm making a sort of accounting software, in theory for my personnal use. I'm using a DB generated auto_increment ID for almost all my objects, but for some specific cases I need a "parallel" more open ID that won't be primary key but could be manipulated by the user(yeah, I've read lots of questions about "you don't need a consecutive Primary Key", and i understand it and agree, but let me remark that this column **won't be the primary key**, lets call it just a "human-not-computer-expert friendly ID") matching these conditions:

- The Id should auto increment when no parameters given.
- When a number is given as a parameter that number should be used if not occupied, if occupied throw an exception.
- The user should be asked if he/she wants to fill the missing IDs by `DELETE`s and whatever other operations, so if the user "say yes", the minimum missing ID should be automatically found and used.

I have no problem with doing this "by hand" in c#, but are there some way to achieve something like this in MySQL directly? I've read in the MySQL documentation that `AUTO_INCREMENT` does fulfill my first two conditions, but even if it fills missing deleted numbers by default, which I'm not sure of, I don't want it to do that by default, I need the software to ask first, or at least to do it based on a configuration pre established by the user.

Therefore I think I should do it by hand in c#(at least the last part, but i suspect i will be forced to do it entirely), which brings the question about `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

So, the MYSQL documentation says:

> If the previous statement returned an error, the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is undefined. For transactional tables, if the statement is rolled back due to an error, the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is left undefined. For manual ROLLBACK, the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is not restored to that before the transaction; it remains as it was at the point of the ROLLBACK.

I understand that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is basically useless if the previous `INSERT` statement fails for whatever reason.

If that's the case, there's no way to retrieve the last inserted ID that ensures a known behaviour when something fails? Something like when `INSERT` fails returns 0 or a SQL exception? And if there's no other way what is the standard way of doing it(I suppose `MAX(Id)` won't do it), if something like a standard way exists... or should I just stop trying to do it at one go and do first the updates, check if all went ok, and then do a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID`?

To sum up:

- Are there some way to achieve a column of consecutive numbers that fulfill the given conditions in MySQL directly?
- What's with `LAST_INSERT_ID`? Should I give up and don't use it directly?

Comment: use auto increments, don't pass the value, accept what returns back, you will never achieve perfect ordering without gaps and will waste too much time on this

Comment: So you are telling me that I should forget about the other ID? I don't mind what happens with primary key, if the DB is OK all is OK. But it's not acceptable for the other ID, i know it for my own experience. I've worked more than 10 years in the same sector I'll use this software. An auto incremental AND user manipulable ID apart from the DB ID is needed.

Comment: Why: if you have 200 companies but the company number 15 don't work anymore with you, you can reuse that number if you want, keeping the DB history with the DB primary key. At the same time, you know that the software will auto generate next ID if you don't specify the opposite. It have to be done, by hand in c# if strictly necessary.

Comment: Alright I will find an answer I wrote up recently concerning this. Most of the time gaps come down to OCD non-normative behavior. People that iron their underwear. Can't sleep at night. Don't understand the innodb engine.

Comment: By the way are you expecting someone to write the c# of it for you? That is simple but too broad

Comment: Of course not! Don't misunderstand me, I'm just asking if there are some way to do it directly with MYSQL instead to have to code it. It's simply that since the MYSQL documentation says that you can specify a number in a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column I thought it will be worth to ask. I won't even discuss if it would be just better to code it and forgot MYSQL(I don't have the knowledge to discuss it without even trying it), just asking if it's possible and somewhat feasible.

Comment: It takes the chat servers a day or so to update the cache (for 20 rep plus) but see if you can chat here in my [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situation 1, knowing an id that you want inserted into an `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Honoring that the AI is not a PK as described.

```
-- drop table a12b;
create table a12b
(   id varchar(100) primary key,
    ai_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    thing varchar(100) not null,
    key(ai_id)
);

insert a12b (id,thing) values ('a','fish'); -- ai_id=1
insert a12b (id,thing) values ('b','dog'); -- 2
insert a12b (id,thing) values ('b2','cat'); -- 3
delete from a12b where id='b';
insert a12b(id,ai_id,thing) values ('b',2,'dog with spots'); -- 2 ******** right here
insert a12b (id,thing) values ('z','goat'); -- 4

select * from a12b;
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | ai_id | thing          |
+----+-------+----------------+
| a  |     1 | fish           |
| b  |     2 | dog with spots |
| b2 |     3 | cat            |
| z  |     4 | goat           |
+----+-------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Situation 2, having a system where you delete rows at some point. And want to fill those explicitly deleted gaps later: See my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421025/mysql-contiguous-sequential-rows-field-even-on-delete-and-insert/39422295#39422295)

Situation 3 (INNODB has a bunch of gaps sprinkled all over):

This was not part of the question. Perhaps use a left join utilizing a helper table (at least for ints not varchars. But then again we are talking about ints). If you need to spot a gap without knowing, shoot for a left join with a helper table (loaded up with numbers). I know it sounds lame, but helper tables are lean and mean and get the job done. The following would be a helper table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33666394

### INNODB Gap Anomaly

using the above table with 4 rows, continue with:

```
insert a12b (id,thing) values ('z','goat'); -- oops, problem, failed, but AI is incremented behind the scene
insert a12b (id,thing) values ('z2','goat'); -- 6 (you now have a gap)

data:
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | ai_id | thing          |
+----+-------+----------------+
| a  |     1 | fish           |
| b  |     2 | dog with spots |
| b2 |     3 | cat            |
| z  |     4 | goat           |
| z2 |     6 | goat           |
+----+-------+----------------+
```

There are a ton of ways to generate gaps. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362042) and [That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363271)

Comment: I'll try to implement what you proposed in your linked answer and say something here. Thanks for the help at the chat ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck. Transcript [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33508361#33508361)